# Different records in tables "cart_product" and "order_detail"

Tags: php, prestashop, prestashop-1.7

We have a customer who, as a note, has a lot of daily orders.

The issue is that he punctually receives orders that have different records in the cart and order detail (tables "cart_product" and "order_detail").

The file /classes/PaymentModule.php has no override, so it's strange...

Example:

Order ID 1 with 2 records in cart_product.

Order ID 1 with 1 record in order_detail.

Has anything similar ever happened to you?

Thanks in advance.

PS Version is 1.7.2.4

Answer (score 1):

It is very likely that for some reason some product is not considered during the execution of the *PaymentModule.php* **validateOrder()** method

Not having other information, I would investigate replicating the creation of an order from one of the involved carts involved and debugging the execution of that method, in particular the management of the "**package_list**" that is responsible for the creation of **order_detail**.

Also consider to update Prestashop core to the latest version because the first 1.7.x were full of bugs about it.

Comment: Thank you very much for your response.

Yes, it is a rare occurrence, and difficult to produce; but your suggestion is very valid. We are going to debug an affected cart locally, to see if we can locate the error....
Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

If this happens with the same product - duplicate it and delete older version.
Maybe there is some undebuggable error in connected db fields.
Sometimes presta try to split one order in two because of product quantity/shipping rules etc.
Maybe second order creation failed.